# How to retrive data from database in proper format html

Tags: php, css, database

I have product table in database. there are few categories such as product title, description, feature etc

For Example, i want to display `$obj_p->description` in list form like

SKU: B00YO9QCSW 5th Generation Processor !!

Intel Core i5 5th Gen 2.2 / 2.7 Ghz Processor 13.3" QHD Screen

1. Intel Integrated Graphics 4 GB RAM,
2. 128 GB SSD  No Optical Drive
3. Webcam
4. Bluetooth
5. WiFi
6. BackLit K/B
7. Windows 8.1 Pro

---

Stored data of description appeared in database as below format!

SKU: B00YO9QCSW

5th Generation Processor !!

Intel Core i5 5th Gen 2.2 / 2.7 Ghz Processor,

13.3" QHD Screen, Intel Integrated Graphics,

4 GB RAM, 128 GB SSD, No Optical Drive,

Webcam, Bluetooth, WiFi, BackLit K/B, Windows 8.1 Pro

I have done code like this!

```
 <div class="span4">
   <div class="product">
       <div class="product-image full-width">
       <a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/product_detail.php?productID=<?php echo($obj_p->productID); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/catalog/<?php echo("$obj_p->product_name/$obj_p->product_image"); ?>" alt="<?php echo($obj_p->product_name); ?>" title="<?php echo($obj_p->product_name); ?>" /></a></div>
       <div class="view-count full-width"><?php echo($obj_p->view_count); ?> views</div>
       <div class="product-price full-width">$ <?php echo($obj_p->unit_price); ?></div>
       </div>  
   </div> 
 <div class="span4">   
   <label><?php echo($obj_p->product_name); ?></label>
    <div class="product-description"> <p> <?php echo($obj_p->description); ?></p></div>
    <div class="spacer11pxH full-width"></div>
 </div>
```

Here are Screenshots of table database and column.

### [image: Table preview column]

[image: Table preview]

Comment: if you want to have same enters inch your html after dumping descriptions process your text with `nl2br` php function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Except for Armen comment, I have troubles understanding the actual question. Did you try something which does not work or anything?

Comment: What is your EXACT Problem?

Comment: sorry , updated question again! mistaken posted before complete question

Comment: Are you asking how to make the stored text into a numbered list? Where one does not exist in that originally stored data

Comment: @riggsFolly yes, stored data in database, plan text form, i want to retrieve it back in list form! is this possible?

Comment: Well only if you write some code to make it into a numbered list, there is no magic convertion.

Comment: i can understand. How to convert them each line in new line, is this possible? @riggsFolly

Comment: You would be better off capturing the data in a more organised fashion if that is what you want to do with it.

Comment: @riggsfolly thanks for you kind time. lets see, if any other, can help me! i am also searching around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to display data from your database in HTML text? If so...

Have you tried using AJAX to return the stored data from your database?

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<body onLoad="getInformation()">
<div class="span4">
<div class="product">
<div class="product-image full-width">
<span id="productInformation"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Your JavaScript would look something like this:

```
function getInformation(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("productInformation").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
var url = "http://yourPHPURL.com/getInformation.php";
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

And finally your PHP / SQL code would look something like this:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
//Connects to the database
$dbc = mysql_pconnect($host,$user, $password);

//Selects the database to use and opens it
$dbname = "DBname";
@mysql_select_db($dbname) OR die ('Cannot connect to database:'. mysql_error());

//Makes the required query to the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM database;";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Returns the item searched for by the user to AJAX
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo("Details:");
echo($row['product_name']);
echo(<br><br>);
echo($row['description']);
}
?>
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for...